# Fast string insertion at front in c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I need to insert strings at the beginning. Right now I use `StringBuilder.Insert(0, stringToInsert)` to insert at front, but it's taking a lot of time (around 2 mins for 80,000 strings).

The `append()` method runs a lot faster (30 secs for 80,000 strings), but it's not the order that I need. How can I reverse the order of the strings (and not the string itself) and decrease the insertion time?

Comment: *How can I reverse the order of the strings (and not the string itself)* I don't know, where are you getting the strings from? Is it as simple as looping over an array backwards or using `Enumerable.Reverse`? You can always reverse all the strings and then build the string builder and then reverse the whole thing.

Comment: You'd probably gain nothing by doing that because it'd take additional time to reverse this strings. StringBuilders Insert method is the best option in your case.

Comment: To downvoters, do you read, it says 80,000 strings and 30 seconds, this is a performance related problem and not a homework, if size of 80,000 strings is large enough, reversing may even take longer.

Comment: Have you tried adding all the strings to a list and using string.Join to create the final string?

Comment: First of all I'd suggest reversing the order in which the source strings are processed. If it's not possible (e.g. the strings are read from a stream) you could consider caching them in a stack and then popping and appending (as @Dorin pointed out using an array and reversed iteration might be even faster) - that is, of course, if all the strings can be fitted into memory at once (which I assume is possible since their concatenation can be stored in a string built using `StringBuilder`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, reversing the enumerable is **much** faster.

For example:

```
var numStrings = 80000;
var strings = new List<String>();
for(var i = 0; i < numStrings; i++)
{
    strings.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var str in Enumerable.Reverse(strings))
    sb.Append(str);

sw.Stop();
sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump(); // 13 milliseconds
sb.Dump();

sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var str in strings)
    sb.Insert(0, str);

sw.Stop();
sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump(); // 42063 milliseconds
sb.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you can put them into an array, and nothing can stop you to do it if you have enough memory, Iterate the array of strings using an index in reverse order and then use append. This should be really fast.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder()
for(i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    s.Append(array[i]);
}
```

Another method would be to use Reverse with Join. But the previous method should do it in a fast manner
`string.Join("", array.Reverse())`